# angular filereader event emiiter

Tags: angular, filereader, eventemitter

I have a angular4 app, where the user will browser a file and I read the file using the filereader and send the complete file in the evenemitter. Below is the code for reading the file.

```
  readThis(inputValue: any): void {
    const file: File = inputValue.files[0];
    this.myReader.onloadend = function(e){
      // you can perform an action with readed data here
      var lines = this.result.split('\n');

    };    
    this.myReader.readAsText(file);
    this.filereadcomplete.emit(this.myReader.readAsText(file);  
  }
```

Comment: You haven't asked any question.

Comment: Oh Sorry, after read is processed I want the complete file that is read to be sent when I emit the event.

Comment: Here's the documentation, containing an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload. You need to submit from *inside* the callback, passed to *onload*.